# Excluding insert of specific rows when copying data in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I use code below to copy and insert data in same table in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO table (product_id, value, branch_id)
SELECT product_id, value, "71"
  FROM table
 WHERE branch_id = "53"
```

It works well for copying and inserting all data. In this case it copies rows with branch_id=53, adds new rows for every copied row and instead of 53 branch_id 71 is inserted.

But now I have some rows with branch_id=71 already inserted so I need to exclude insert of that existing data by stating something like `WHERE branch_id = "53" AND product_id != "product_id that already exists in row with branch_id=71"`

How to do that in MySQL?

Comment: Is there a unique index on `(product_id, branch_id)`? You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to make it skip rows that would create a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a unique composite index on `(product_id, branch_id)`, you can use `INSERT IGNORE`. Then if it tries to create a duplicate row, it will just skip that entry silently.

If not, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table (product_id, value, branch_id)
SELECT t1.product_id, t1.value, '71'
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t2.branch_id = '71'
WHERE t1.branch_id = '53' AND t2.product_id IS NULL
```